# The above error occurred in the <Context.Consumer> component:

Tags: reactjs, console, react-dom, consumer, webcontext

npm test is answering like this. What about my Context.consumer?

[image]

Comment: something wrong in the Users component.

Comment: Now I copied the Users.js file in the project which is noerror but it hasn't changed

Comment: @datokmak Have you fixed this issue ?